# Ubuntu 14.04.2 nVidia 6200 proprietary drivers cause artefacts on unity/GUI

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I had recently reformatted and installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 32-Bit desktop and my nVidia graphics card is playing up showing horrible artefacts on Unity.  The open source driver that Ubuntu installs by default works, but slows down Unity and Kodi.

What I don't understand is this was working before when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 32-Bit desktop last year and now I reinstalled it and it doesn't work.  It also worked on the last Ubuntu LTS release before this one, what happened?  Am I doing something wrong?

Specs:

- CPU: Intel Pentium 4 2.80 Ghz 32-bit
- RAM: 768MB
- HDDs: 2 x 1TB Western Digital
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 6200 512MB AGP (EVGA Brand)
- DVD: LG DVD-ROM/CD Burner combo drive
- Sound card: ASUS Xonar PCI

I tried installing the proprietary drivers via the GUI using the "Additional Drivers"
method and after reinstalling the OS via the terminal using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Ubuntu and Linux Kernel Version:
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-33-generic i686)

nVidia Driver Details (driver from Ubuntu default repositories for closed-source drivers):

Architecture: i386 (32-Bit x86)

Driver Version: 304.125-0ubuntu0.0.1

NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of the driver you're running?   Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Done! Added the driver information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: Use the above link to install the 346.47 version of the drivers from `xorg-edgers`.  If that would still give you problems, leave a comment below.  ;-)